# Any way to offset results with AWS SDK for PHP?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I'm currently working on scanning a folder in my S3 bucket and removing files that are no longer in my database. The problem is that I have millions of files, so no way of scanning this in one go.

```
// get files
$files = $s3->getIterator('ListObjects', array(
    "Bucket" => $S3Bucket,
    "Prefix" => 'collections/items/',
    "Delimiter" => '/'
), array(
    'return_prefixes' => true,
    'names_only' => true,
    'limit' => 10
));
```

The documentation included something about limiting results, but I can't find anything about offsetting. I want to be able to start from 0, scan 500 items, remove them, stop, save the last scanned index and then run the script again, start from the saved index (501), scan 500 items, and so on.

Does the SDK offer some sort of offset option? Is it called something else? Or can you recommend a different method of scanning such a large folder?

Comment: why do you want to do this? the s3->getIerator() function does exactly that under the hood btw

Comment: But if I run the script and it crashes, I will have to start over, right?

Comment: remember the last key you processed and start from there. in your code $s3 is instance of s3Client? Try add last successful key fetched as Marker parameter: $s3->getIterator('ListObjects', array('Bucket' => 'my-bucket', 'Marker' => 'lastkey'));

Comment: Marker is what the iterator uses too. There are no integer indexes with S3

Comment: did a quick test with Marker. works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember the last key you processed and use it as the Marker parameter.

```
$files = $s3->getIterator('ListObjects', array(
  "Bucket" => "mybucket",
  "Marker" => "last/key"
));
```

BTW, dont set Limit, its slowing down. Limit 10 will cause a request to the API every 10 objects, the API can return up to 1000 objects per request.

Comment: I only used limit 10 while building the script. I want to set it to about 20k and run it multiple times until it finishes scanning the folder. Thanks!